# Why can't I write the tensorflow predicted images from google earth engine to google cloud bucket vía google colab?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

I've taken the example from https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb but at the "doPrediction(image_base, user_folder, kernel_buffer, region)" part, it throw's me this error when ends writeng the patches:

> ...WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:96:
> disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope)
> is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions
> for updating: non-resource variables are not supported in the long
> term Running command using Cloud API.  Set --no-use_cloud_api to go
> back to using the API
>
> W0628 01:00:34.470155 139679737870208 **init**.py:48] file_cache is
> unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py",
> line 33, in 
> from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py",
> line 37, in 
> from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/**init**.py",
> line 44, in autodetect
> from . import file_cache   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py",
> line 41, in 
> "file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth" ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using
> oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth W0628 01:00:35.849350
> 139679737870208 **init**.py:48] file_cache is unavailable when using
> oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py",
> line 33, in 
> from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py",
> line 37, in 
> from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/**init**.py",
> line 44, in autodetect
> from . import file_cache   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py",
> line 41, in 
> "file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth" ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using
> oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth Name
> "projects/earthengine-public/assets/FCNN-ELQUI-pisco_" is invalid. The
> portion of the Asset name following "projects/*/assets/" must have at
> least 3 segments and at most 10 segments.

maybe it's something about the folder where I intend to write the patches, that is googlecloud bucket.

Comment: It's pretty unclear for me the issue that you are facing. Did you tried to just write a file to storage from colab? Did you provided the right permisions to your colab service account?

Comment: Thanks, @Chris32. I create all the permisions I think are needed as indicated in colab example:
-from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
-ee.Authenticate() and ee.Initialize()
-even !earthengine authenticate.

Also I think the problem is issolated to this line of code:
`!earthengine upload image --asset_id={out_image_asset} {out_image_file} {jsonFile}`
where it cannot upload the image from google cloud drive bucket to the earth engine as a new asset, just by doing it manually in the GEE platform.